# How can I validate user input to be integer only in razor syntax in cshtml file?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-webpages

I have this problem to find out if the user's input is a leap year or not. Still, I don't know how to validate the input to be positive integer only. I need to exclude the float type in **RAZOR** syntax. Can anyone help me with the code, please?

```
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
     }

    @{
        var leap_year = "";
        var error_mes = "";    
        if (IsPost)
        {
           var yr = Request["year"];
           if (yr.AsInt() < 0) 
           {
              error_mes = "Please Input positive integer";
           } 
           else if ((yr.AsInt()%4 == 0) || (yr.AsInt()%400 == 0))
           {
              leap_year = yr + " is leap year";
           }
           else
           {
              leap_year = yr + " is not leap year";
           }
        }
     }

     <html>
     <head>
        <title>Leap Year</title>

     </head>
     <body>
        <h3>Please input to check for leap year</h3>
        <form method="post">
           <label for="year">Year</label><br />
           <p><input type="text" name="year" /></p>
           <p><input type="submit" value="Check" /></p>
        </form>
        <p>@error_mes @leap_year</p>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: It is not view's responsibility to do these calculations. The validations should go in Model and logic can go in the controller.

Comment: The web sends and receives strings for most things, so you have to perform your own conversions. `Request["Year"]` will return a string, so you might want to use `Convert.ToInt32()`. However ASP.NET can do model binding for you, e.g. `public ActionResult YourAction(int Year)`
ASP.NET will try to parse an int value from a request parameter but if it's missing or invalid, e.g. `../YourAction?year=blah` then it won't match the method.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal There are no controllers in ASP.NET Web Pages

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET Web Pages framework provides an `IsInt()` helper method that determines whether a value is an integer:

```
if(Request["year"].IsInt())
{
    if(Request["year"].AsInt() < 0)
    {
       ...blah blah blah
    }
}
else
{
    error_mes = "Please Input integer";
}
```

The method is a wrapper around the [Int32.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) method.